# Use const lvalue std::array as template parameter

Tags: c++, arrays, c++17

I've successfully implemented a struct using and manipulating a `const std::string_view&` as template parameter. Now I'm struggling with doing it iteratively on a `std::array<_, std::string_view>`. I'm using GCC 10.3 / C++17.

My first template function takes a `std::string_view` and create a new, modified, `std::string_view`. In my case, this is a constexpr "ToUpper" function. I've simplified it to `Fake` in my code bellow which just gives the same `std::string_view`.
I would like to apply this method (`Fake`) to each element in my `std::array` and return it as constexpr.

Here's my code: https://godbolt.org/z/c3vdjrrjo

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <utility>

template <const std::string_view& V>
struct Fake {
  static constexpr auto value = V;
};

template <int N, const std::array<std::string_view, N>& array>
struct ArrayFake {
  template <std::size_t... Is>
  static constexpr auto f(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return std::array<std::string_view, N>{Fake<array[Is]>::value...};
  }

  static constexpr auto value = f(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
};

int main() {
  static constexpr auto bang = "Plop";
  static constexpr auto bang3 = "Plop2";
  static constexpr auto kArray = std::array<std::string_view, 3>{bang, bang, bang3};
  constexpr auto kNewArray = ArrayFake<3, kArray>::value;
  for (const auto& n : kNewArray) {
    std::cout << n << "\n";
  }
}
```

I can't get rid of this compilation error:

```
<source>:93:65: error: '& kArray.std::array<std::basic_string_view<char>, 3>::_M_elems[0]' is not a valid template argument of type 'const string_view&' {aka 'const std::basic_string_view<char>&'} because 'kArray.std::array<std::basic_string_view<char>, 3>::_M_elems[0]' is not a variable
   93 |         return std::array<std::string_view, N>{Fake<array[Is]>::value...};
```

I understand I'm doing something not correctly, but how am I supposed to effectively iterate through my array to create another std::array constexpr value ?

Comment: Could you maybe explain what it is that you are actually trying to achieve? Why are you creating templates which only take a string_view as a parameter? What is the point then, why do you need templates at all? By the way, template parameters are supposed to be types or integers, not concrete instances of types. I think you totally missed the point of templates.

Comment: I've eddited my question. I'd like to apply `Fake` to each array element and return another array containing these modification.

Comment: @MarkPopovic template parameters can be values too. There are non-type template parameter and in recent standards they can be more than just integers

Comment: Probably you're better off rewriting this using `constexpr` all the way (no templates)

Comment: @MicroVirus could you provide an example ? I don't see how I can use a plain constexpr function to write `Fake` (which is supposed to modify its string_view, and especially, change its size. I currently do it by allocating a std::array from the string_view and then transforming it into a string_view).

Comment: No sorry, I don't have an example. A trick I've seen used (in an constexpr xml parser) is to use two pass: the first pass to determine the structure and size for each template argument for each string_view and the second pass to perform the actual operation within that 'pre-determined' size.

Answer (score 2):

According to C++17 N4659 [[temp.arg.nontype#2]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.arg.nontype#2):

> For a non-type template-parameter of reference or pointer type, the
> value of the constant expression shall not refer to (or for a pointer
> type, shall not be the address of):
>
> - **a subobject**,
> - a temporary object,
> - a string literal,
> - the result of a typeid expression, or
> - a predefined `__func__` variable.

where subobject is defined in [[intro.object#2]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.object#2):

> Objects can contain other objects, called *subobjects*. A subobject can
> be a member subobject ([class.mem]), a base class subobject (Clause
> [class.derived]), or an array element.

Since you use `array[Is]` as `Fake`'s non-type template argument, which refers to subobject `kArray._M_elems[Is]`, this is ill-formed in C++17.

It's worth noting that [P1907](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1907r1.html) looses some restrictions on non-type template parameters, which makes your code [well-formed](https://godbolt.org/z/PbcTxT75M) in C++20.

Comment: This means there is no way to implement such pattern in C++17 ? I was wondering if passing from an array to a tuple would change anything but it seems that's not the case, considering the definition of a subobject :(

Comment: @Armassarion well maybe you could use template parameter packs instead of the input array to build the output array?

Comment: @MicroVirus I successfully did that, but the function I currently use returns a `std::array`. Unless it's possible to convert a std::array to a parameter pack, I'm stuck again :(

Comment: @Armassarion. You should post another question and describe what you tried.